# python ModuleNotFoundError after running pip install - e .

Tags: python, pip, distutils

I'm trying to compile and install the following python package, system-wide:
https://github.com/mathurinm/BlitzL1/

(note that the `init.py` of the module is inside a folder named `python`)

So I run, at the root of the repo,

```
pip install -e .
```

I get:

```
zongo@zongo-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~/workspace/BlitzL1$ pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///home/zongo/workspace/BlitzL1
Installing collected packages: blitzl1
  Running setup.py develop for blitzl1
Successfully installed blitzl1

zongo@zongo-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~/workspace/BlitzL1$ ipython
Python 3.6.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 26 2018, 09:53:17) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.0.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import blitzl1                                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8bb5a22c28e9> in <module>
----> 1 import blitzl1

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blitzl1'
```

after trial and error, I found that renaming the `python` folder to `blitzl1` and  replacing, in `setup.py`:

```
package_dir = {"blitzl1": "python"},
```

by

```
package_dir = {"blitzl1": "blitzl1"},
```

makes it possible to import the package. Why is the first one not working?

By the way:

```
zongo@zongo-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~/workspace/BlitzL1$ which pip
/home/zongo/anaconda3/bin/pip
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to a long lasting issue in `pip` with installing a package in develop mode when the package directory is not in the same folder as the `setup.py`. See [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/230) for more info.

To be clearer, if the package name is `my_package` and the structure of the source is:

```
|- setup.py
|- src
  |- __init__.py
  |- ...
```

with `package_dir={'my_package':'src'}`, installing the package with either `pip install -e .` or `python setup.py develop` will raise the error reported by the OP.
A way to mitigate this is to change to `package_dir={'':'src'}` and change the structure of the repo to

```
|- setup.py
|- src
  |- mypackage
     |- __init__.py
     |- ...
```